# I am having a hard time retrieving data from json object

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "formname": ["Myapname", {
        "operation": ["add", {
            "values": {
                "confirm_code": "12345",
                "ID": 222333333,
                "user_id": "10000"
            },
            "status": "Success"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have tried this below:

```
   posting.done(function( data ) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(obj["ID"]);
      });
    });
```

But I am not getting back anything all I see `undefined`

can someone assist me with what am doing wrong

Comment: Point of interest here.. once the JSON is parsed, you have an object.   The fact that the object comes from JSON has almost nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` is not a property of `obj`, it's property of it's nested object. You can get it using `obj.formname[1].operation[1].values.ID`

```js
var obj = {
  "formname": ["Myapname", {
    "operation": ["add", {
      "values": {
        "confirm_code": "12345",
        "ID": 222333333,
        "user_id": "10000"
      },
      "status": "Success"
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(
  obj.formname[1].operation[1].values.ID
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I just start working with Javascript on this level was searching the whole day even this obj.formname[1].operation[1].values.ID and was following this this website http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_json/ then I came here so thanks again @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @youngreactNative : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Heh am having another issue when ever I parse the id the values at the end change that is return from the surver @Pranav

Comment: @youngreactNative : what is the change?

Comment: It have worked an the app is great now thank you so much @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @youngreactNative : glad to help :)